# How to return row that has string inside, instead of matching the whole string?

Tags: python

I have this code called `get.py`:

```
import urllib2, base64, csv, sys  
from sys import argv

request = urllib2.Request("https://example.com/test.csv")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
sheet = csv.read(data.split('\n'),delimiter=',')

def main():
    for row in sheet:
        if arg in row:
            print "Host"+row[5] + "IP"+row[6]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

For example, when I run `./get.py 127`, I want to get all IPs that have `127` in them.

Comment: Can you explain the format of the csv file? Also, to embed code, just put 4 spaces before each line of code; it's currently embedded as a quote.

Comment: csv is just regular csv with IP like 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.3, 127.0.0.2, I just want to run ./get.py 127 and get every result that has 127 in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this out:

```
import urllib2, base64, csv, sys
from sys import argv

request = urllib2.Request("https://example.com/test.csv")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
sheet = csv.reader(data.split('\n'), delimiter=',')

def main(arg):
    for row in sheet:
        if len(row) == 0:
            continue

        if arg in row[6]:
            print("Host" + row[5] + ", IP" + row[6])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(argv[1])
```

I tried this with my python 2.7 interpreter and it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You currently check if the string argument is in the list at all, whereas you should be checking the specific element *of* the list (it appears to be the element at index 6):

```
import urllib2, base64, csv, sys
from sys import argv

request = urllib2.Request("https://example.com/test.csv")
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
data = response.read()
sheet = csv.read(data.split('\n'),delimiter=',')

def main(arg):
    ip = arg[1]
    for row in sheet:
        if ip in row[6]:
            print("Host" + row[5] + "IP" + row[6])

if name == "main":
    main(argv)
```

Comment: I get index out of range when it got to if ip in row[6]:

Comment: This means that the csv file has fewer columns than you thought. Try printing `len(row)` to the screen and seeing how many entries each row actually has.

Comment: I get 37 when I type len(row)

Comment: You'll need to manually inspect the csv, as it's definitely a different format to what you expected. You need to see if the format is like [this](https://pastebin.com/5zrHCf3j) or [this](https://pastebin.com/qjUxHUg7), as the code is written for the second case.

Comment: Cool, just check for empty rows as shown in pgngp's solution.